# Uploading Image path in Linux Hosting Server (Java)

Tags: java, linux, file-upload, file-io, openshift

I am working on an application in which users are allowed to upload Image files. I am follow ing the approach of saving the file in a directory and saving its name in database for retrieval.

```
inputStream = file.getInputStream();
BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
imBuff = Scalr.resize(imBuff, 200);
File dir = new File("/opt/uploads/contactImages");
if(!dir.exists()){
     dir.mkdirs();
}
ImageIO.write(imBuff, "png", new File("/opt/uploads/contactImages"));
```

Hence with the above code my files are getting uploaded in opt/uploads/contactImages folder and is working fine in my local environment.

But in production I have hosted my war on openshift server. The images are not getting created there, may be because I dont have the root access to create such directory? What should be the possible approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using openshift variable
System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") uploads the file in app-root/data directory

Reference
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know we all are using instance of App/Web server on openshift, we dont have standalone servers here so we wont be having write access to server, instead try uploading BLOB object in database from which you can retrieve it easily

Comment: Yes I understand that, but we at-least have rights to uploads our war, then definitely we have rights to upload other files, I am not willing to go to go through BLOB way.

Comment: I am not sure over this, we can upload our war but we can't create any dir over the server. I will look into this and will get back to you.

Comment: tushar did you try this??
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift